# Orbit Around Arbitrary Axis

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I am working on a game in OpenGL using libGDX on Android. I currently have a sphere on the screen, and a camera is orbiting the sphere around the Y axis. I have a virtual joystick that I want to use to move the camera in the direction that the joystick is pointing. I already have the angle that the joystick is pointing.

I'm not sure about how to go about moving the camera in 3D space based on the angle that I have from my 2D joystick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example](http://tutorialrandom.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-rotate-in-3d-using-opengl-proper.html) is done for iOS, but can easily be applied to any platform really. It will show you how to do rotations in 3d.

If you keep an up, right and forward vector of your joystick, you can apply it to your camera easily using that example.

Comment: I'll give it a try and see what I can come up with, not too familiar with Obj-C but looks easy enough to understand.